# How do I get an error from `pop_back()` if `size()` is 0?

Tags: c++, vector

I was explaining to a coworker why we have small test with sanitizers on them. He asked about popping a vector too many times and if it was an exception, assert, UB and which sanitizer catches it

It appears NONE catches them. Address and memory will if you call `back()` after popping too many times but if you pop and do `size()` you get a large invalid value due to wrapping

Is there a way I can get an assert or exception or runtime termination when I pop too many times? I really thought a debug build without sanitizers would have caught that (with an assert or exception)

I use clang sanitizer but build options with gcc will also be helpful

Comment: Doesn't `size()` return an unsigned type?  It should be impossible for it to be less than zero.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I wasn't being literal. I used printf. -1 and max value are both the same bit pattern. My point was it was not correct to wrap and I wanted some kind of warning

Comment: `if (v.size() == 0) throw "curses, foiled again."; v.pop_back();`

Comment: `size()` does return a `size_type` which is unsigned. If it is getting casted to a signed type though it could end up negative cause of narrowing. Most times the compiler should warn you of implicit narrowing though.

Comment: @floomby -- if it's being cast to a signed type there is no implicit narrowing; a cast is always explicit -- it's something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: @Pete Becker -- Implicit casting is when the compiler inserts the cast for you. It does this for many things. I can call `void f(long x)` with `int` and it is fine. It is implicitly converted to a long for purposes of calling f.

Comment: @EricStotch *"I wasn't being literal."* -- I'd advise you to try to be literal when dealing with anything related to debugging. A small detail like whether or not a value is unsigned can be highly significant. (As an example, for this question, `size()` returning a signed value would have indicated that your vectors are not `std::vector`, which would affect which settings are helpful. Details matter.)

Comment: @floomby — you’re describing an **implicit conversion**, not a cast. Yes, some people use “cast” as a synonym for “conversion”, but that’s just sloppiness.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Popping from an empty container is Undefined Behavior, and yes, that can include `size_t` taking negative values. This is more than theoretical; the optimizer may see inlined functions and reorder instructions that would cause such negative numbers. Optimizers only have to be sensible for programs with defined behavior.

Comment: @MSalters good point, I never thought of that.  Good luck detecting that negative number though.

Comment: @JaMiT alright since there was enough confusion and enough people asked, I modified the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both libstdc++ and libc++ have a "debug mode" with assertions, that can be enabled using:

- `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` for libstdc++
- `-D_LIBCPP_DEBUG` for libc++

Also `-fsanitize=undefined` appears to catch it, but the error message is much more cryptic.

Comment: `-fsanitize=undefined` DOES NOT do it on my system (clang 12.0.1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) however `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` worked perfectly (with and without sanitizers in my one test)

Comment: @EricStotch It worked [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zj7aEvbTz).

Comment: Funny. I didn't think of doing a pop without a push. I did it like this which removed that error https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ffqexhs6j

Comment: It seems the sanitizer only handles the case where the vector isn't initialized and thus a null-pointer; but not the case when pop_back is called too much on a non-empty vector. I would guess the latter is also a fairly common bug in practice.

Answer (score 2):

The sanitizers may need some annotations to do a good job on library types. `g++ -fsanitize=address -D_GLIBCXX_SANITIZE_VECTOR` ([documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_macros.html)), `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -fsanitize=address` or `clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -fsanitize=address -D_GLIBCXX_SANITIZE_VECTOR -D__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__` (the need for this last macro is a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103453)) all detect the issue and print a message

```
=================================================================
==12312==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: bad parameters to __sanitizer_annotate_contiguous_container:
      beg     : 0x602000000010
      end     : 0x602000000014
      old_mid : 0x602000000010
      new_mid : 0x60200000000c
    #0 0x7f6a9db3b707 in __sanitizer_annotate_contiguous_container ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_poisoning.cpp:362
    #1 0x55b9dcd1fc41 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl::_Asan<std::allocator<int> >::_S_adjust(std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl&, int*, int*) (/tmp/a.out+0x1c41)
    #2 0x55b9dcd1fb66 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl::_Asan<std::allocator<int> >::_S_shrink(std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl&, unsigned long) (/tmp/a.out+0x1b66)
    #3 0x55b9dcd1f6c4 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::pop_back() (/tmp/a.out+0x16c4)
    #4 0x55b9dcd1f36d in main (/tmp/a.out+0x136d)
    #5 0x7f6a9d57fe49 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:314
    #6 0x55b9dcd1f199 in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x1199)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: bad-__sanitizer_annotate_contiguous_container ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_poisoning.cpp:362 in __sanitizer_annotate_contiguous_container
==12312==ABORTING
```

Note that there is no need for something as complicated as the sanitizers for this case, as mentioned in the other answer, libraries often have debug modes. For instance with libstdc++, defining `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` enables the full debug mode (ABI-incompatible with normal mode)

```
/usr/include/c++/11/debug/vector:523:
In function:
    void std::__debug::vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::pop_back() [with _Tp = int; 
    _Allocator = std::allocator<int>]

Error: attempt to access an element in an empty container.

Objects involved in the operation:
    sequence "this" @ 0x0x7ffe20bf5f80 {
      type = std::__debug::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >;
    }
```

while defining `_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS` enables much lighter assertions and preserves the ABI, but gives less information about the error

```
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:1227: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pop_back() [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]: Assertion '!this->empty()' failed.
```

and defining `_LIBCPP_DEBUG` with libc++ prints

```
/usr/lib/llvm-11/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1703: _LIBCPP_ASSERT '!empty()' failed. vector::pop_back called for empty vector
```